# Azure Static Web App - linking to multiple api:s in Azure API Management (APIM)

Tags: azure, static, apim

We have an Azure Static Web App from which we wish to consume a large number of endpoints (~100) from a number (~10) of api:s - all exposed by one single instance of Azure API Management (APIM).

If we simply try to invoke these endpoints directly from the frontend - we run into CORS issues.

As far as I understand - the proper way of solving is to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-api-management#link-an-azure-api-management-service) the backend api:s to be consumed by the static web app. And since some time back - there is [support](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/new-api-backend-options-in-azure-static-web-apps/ba-p/3516882) for APIM. Great!

The problem is that only (?) api:s at route */api/{operation}* can be used.

Meaning in the case of APIM - I can only (?) use API **without** a url suffix - such as
https://my-apim.azure-api.net/api/my-endpoint.
Which can then be reached by static web app through https://www.my-custom-domain.com/api/my-endpoint

But in APIM - only one single api can have empty url suffix per APIM instance.
So how do I solve the problem of consuming multiple api:s (exposed by APIM) from a single Azure static web site ?

I would prefer not be forced into exposing all 100 endpoints in one gigantic api in APIM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question here. Adding an APIM instance to the backend will (I should probably put "attempt to") proxy ANY requests coming through to `<static-webapp-frontend_url>/api/*` to the SAME route in your APIM instance - i.e. `<APIM_URL>/api/*`. When you add an API (or 10, or 20) you choose the particular APIs suffix for that API and APIM does the reverse proxying for you.

So say for instance I have an Azure Function App which exposes a `GET` and `POST` endpoint on route `/products` thus making the API's fully qualified route `www.example-azure-function-url.com/products`. I then take this API and add it to my APIM instance and give it the suffix of `/product-service/`. If my APIM instance's FQDN is `www.example-APIM-url.com` then that exposed API's route in APIM can reached at `www.example-APIM-url.com/api/product-service/products`. If I then add this APIM instance to the backend of a static web app with a FQDN of `www.static-web-app-example.com` then I can call this exposed API at `www.static-web-app-example.com/api/product-service/products` for `GET` and `POST` operations.

Using this pattern I hope it is clear how your use case would consume APIs via an APIM backend. But do let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Comment: Thx for reply. May I ask if you have tried this yourself ?

In your example above, using  `product-service` as url suffix in APIM, the FQDN would be
`www.example-APIM-url.com/product-service/api/products` 
As you say, routes of type `<static-webapp-frontend_url>/api/*` are routed to the APIM as `<APIM_URL>/api/*` - but APIM_URL in our example is `www.example-APIM-url.com`.

Hence when you add the url suffix - things break. I see no way around this ?

Comment: If I use url suffix `api/product-service` - then it meets above criteria and everything works.